# This program keeps on giving me an error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4

Tags: java, binary, decimal

When I write a code like this one, I always get this error.  It is definitely building the file but is not it just gives me exemption.  I am a beginner.  Can you guys please help me out and really point out the mistake that I am making.

```
public static int binToDec(int i)
{
    int[] numbers;//initialize variable
    int f = 4;
    String iString = "" + i;
    int result = 0;
    int length = iString.length();
    numbers = new int[length];
    int power;
    for(power = iString.length(); power>=0;power--)
    {
    while(f == length && f >= 0)
    {

        numbers[power] = iString.charAt(power)^power;
    }

    length--;
    f--;
    }
    for(int g = 0; g <= numbers.length; g++)//double check constraints
    {
        result = numbers[g] = numbers[power];
    }

        return result;
}
```

The error it is giving me is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4
at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:686)
at BaseConvertor.binToDec(BaseConvertor.java:34)
at BaseConvertorTester.main(BaseConvertorTester.java:10)
```

I also have a tester file.  Here it is:

```
 public class BaseConvertorTester 
  {
public static void main(String args[])

{

    BaseConvertor.binToDec(1010);   

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If a String has length `X`, it means that it has `X` characters which are indexed starting from `0`. So the last character will be at index `X-1`, not `X`.

In your `for` loop you have:

```
for (power = iString.length(); power >= 0; power--)
```

but this implies that, if `iString` has length `4`, it will try to access the character at index `4`, which would be the fifth (non existing in the string, indeed out of range). Try with

```
for (power = iString.length() - 1; power >= 0; power--)
```

Comment: Now, when I try to run it.  It won't run at all.  How can I fix that?

Comment: There are other problems not related to the exception, for example you have an infinite loop `while(f == length && f >= 0) { ... }` since you are not modifying neither `f` or `length` inside the body.

Comment: How could I potentially fix this?  I know I am being a bother but thank you!

Comment: So what is your while loop for?

Comment: My while loop is being used to to convert the binary number into the decimal.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
for(power = iString.length(); power >= 0; power--)
```

to

```
for(power = iString.length(); power > 0; power--)
```

Your loop is starting at 4 then going to 3 then 2 then 1 then 0 which is a total of 5 times when iString.length() is only 4. Changing the >= to > will exclude 0 running it only 4 times.

I'd also change this

```
String iString = "" + i;
```

to

```
String iString = Integer.toString(i);
```

better programming.

Comment: the challenge is not to use any to methods.

Comment: Is this a school challenge? If so your teacher is defeating the purpose of the to methods. Why implement them if you can't use them? Sorry for the rant but I hate teachers that give tons of restrictions on programming when it's not necessary. Anyways good luck on your challenge.